# JS AddEventListener in loop (for all checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I wanted to add event listener to all checkboxes on my page.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="3" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="4" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="5" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="6" value="6">
<!--  .....  -->

<script>
var arr =  document.getElementsByName("sel[]");

var copy = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    copy[i] = arr[i].id;


var checkboxes = [];
var data;


for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
{
    checkboxes[j] = document.getElementById(copy[j]);
    checkboxes[j].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) 
    {
        data = j;
        $.post("/php/ses.php", {data:data});
    }
    else 
    {
        data = (-1)*j;
        $.post("/php/ses.php", {data:data});
    }
 });
</script>
```

It works for every checkbox, but always sends 6 if any checkbox is checked (or -6 when unchecked). I wanted to: 1 and -1 for first chceckbox, 2 and -2 for second etc, not 6/-6 for every.

Comment: why not attach a single event handler to a parent element? The [change event will bubble.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). Also, might be better to use `event.target.id` or `.value` to get your index. It's the scope of the `j` variable: by the time the events fire, `j` will always have iterated to its max value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you use JQuery this code may be more preferable

```
var checkboxes =  $('[name="sel[]"]');

//listen all checkboxes change event
checkboxes.on('change', function(){
    var id = this.value; // id equals j in your code
    $.post("/php/ses.php", { data: this.checked ? id: -id }); // send data id if checked and -id if not checked
});
```

Comment: You are quicker ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use checkboxes data value for your data instead of keeping a separate instance of it.

```js
var arr =  document.getElementsByName("sel[]");
for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
    arr[j].addEventListener('change', (event) => {  
    if (event.target.checked) {
        //$.post("/php/ses.php", {data:data});
        console.log({data: parseInt(event.target.value)});
    }else {
        //$.post("/php/ses.php", {data:data});
        console.log({data: -parseInt(event.target.value)});
    }
 });
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="3" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="4" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="5" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" name="sel[]" id="6" value="6">
</body>
</html>
```

The reason your code ends up with `6` is that your `data` is a global variable and gets updated after each loop, and it ends up with `6` at the end, there is no local `data` for event listener for each item on `arr`.
Please check this to learn more about it [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 0):

While the answer by Prokhor Orlov is correct I want to explain what is wrong in OP. At the moment when event handler fires the `for` loop iterator is already ran out of the loop and has its max value. This error is very common in beginners and the question was asked 100+ times. The solution is also well known, use closure in the loop. Something like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
(function(j){
  checkboxes[j] = document.getElementById(copy[j]);
  checkboxes[j].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      data = j;
      $.post("/php/ses.php", {
        data: data
      });
    } else {
      data = (-1) * j;
      $.post("/php/ses.php", {
        data: data
      });
    }
  });
})(i);
}
```

*Disclaimer*: This is not recommended code in this case